# How to do a Port Proxy?

Tags: proxy, ipv6

As some software doesn't listen to IPv6 port, we often do a port proxy to solve the problem.
For example, the remote desktop in Win2003, we just run
netsh interface portproxy add v6tov4 listenport=3389 connectaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=3389
and then everything goes well.

Now I'd like to visit the Deluge WebUI (127.0.0.1:8112) by IPv6, how to do this in ubuntu???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use xinetd for that.

In this example I'll show how to redirect incoming connections to IPv6 address 2001:db8::1 port 1234 to IPv4 address 192.0.2.1 port 1234. I'll call the configuration/service 'demo':

Put the following configuration in a configuration file called /etc/xinetd.d/demo:

```
service demo
{
    type            = UNLISTED
    port            = 1234
    bind            = 2001:db8::1
    socket_type     = stream
    wait            = no
    user            = nobody
    redirect        = 192.0.2.1 1234
}
```

It also lets you control who can access the service in both the service definition and the /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny files.

```
service demo
{
    ...
    only_from       = 2001:db8::/32
    no_access       = 2001:db8:ffff::/48
    ...
}
```

Other potentially useful option:

```
service demo
{
    ...
    access_times    = 09:45-16:15
    log_on_success  = HOST DURATION
    log_on_failure  = HOST ATTEMPT
    ...
}
```